# Installing lxml on AppVeyor

Tags: python, windows, lxml, appveyor

Trying to build a python project on AppVeyor it fails when trying to install [lxml](http://lxml.de) with the following config:

```
environment:

  matrix:

    - PYTHON: "C:\\Python27-x64"
    - PYTHON: "C:\\Python34-x64"
      DISTUTILS_USE_SDK: "1"
    - PYTHON: "C:\\Python35-x64"

platform:
  - x86

install:
  - "%PYTHON%\\python.exe -m pip install lxml==3.6.4"
```

On a local machine I can get around this by installing one of [these](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml) binary builds as specified [here](http://lxml.de/installation.html#installation). But when running this on AppVeyor I would like to be able to avoid that. (Maybe by building the lxml requirements from source, but how would I do that?)